# How to loop through YAML frontmatter content for use in Liquid? (Jekyll)

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to loop through some values in my frontmatter's `sidebar` property to use in some Liquid loops that also make use of YAML, but it's not working.

Here's the code:

```
---
sidebar: [a, b, c]
---

{% for sidebar in page.sidebar %}
{% for entry in sidebar.entries %}
...
```

I want the code to use a.entries, and then b.entries, and then c.entries, but it's not working. Is that because all the YAML processing happens at once, and then the Jekyll pipeline process moves on to HTML or something?

Comment: I don't understand where are `sidebar.entries`. In front matter ?

Comment: Actually, instead of a, b, c, I'm planning to put paths to yaml files, like this: `site.data.sidebar.entries`. The sidebar.yaml file starts out with `entries:`. So this for loop will cycle through each of the sidebar.yaml files listed here.

Comment: For the real scenario where I'm trying to implement this code, see this [file](https://github.com/tomjohnson1492/documentation-theme-jekyll/blob/gh-pages/urls.txt). I want to avoid repeating the for loop through each sidebar file like I'm doing there. I want to instead merely list the sidebars in the frontmatter or something simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how you can access a data file with a variable name :

```
{% for sidebar in page.sidebar %}
  {% for entry in site.data.sidebars[sidebar].entries %}
   .. do things with datas
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```